# Getting count of branch node of multiple root nodes in Neo4J using Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

As shown in image,
3 root node - A,B,C - likewise D,E,F etc
6 Branch Node - A1,a2,a3,b1,b2,c1
 I want to get the count of branch nodes related to root node.

So I used

```
MATCH (b:branch)-[:branch_of]-(r:root {Root:'A'}) RETURN count(b)
```

It works for Single root,
But I want multiple root- so i used

```
MATCH (r:root),(b:branch),(b)-[:branch_of]-(r {Root:'A'},{Root:'B'},{Root:'C'}) RETURN count(b)
```

But its not working -How to Implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you want. For every root (that has a 'Root' property value in the 'roots' parameter array), get a count of the number of branches.

*By the way, you should indicate the directionality of the relationships in the query. That can make things faster.*

```
MATCH (b:branch)-[:branch_of]-(r:root)
WHERE r.Root IN {roots}
RETURN r, count(b)
```

So, if you only cared about roots "A" and "B", you'd specify a parameter like this:

```
{
  "roots": ['A', 'B']
}
```

Comment: THis is not what i want. I want for selective roots Example- For the above diagram I just want for ROOT a & b NOT c. Then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Got answer myself

```
MATCH (r:root),(b:branch),(b)-[:branch_of]-(r) WHERE r.name="A" OR r.name="B" RETURN count(b)
```

It worked